# Смысл выражения "находиться на одном счету у бога и чёрта"

Tags: смысл

Если начинать вдумываться в очевидные на первый взгляд вещи, то становится непонятно. Вот, например, припев песни из "Гардемаринов":

```
И у черта и у Бога,
На одном видать счету.
Ты российская дорога -
Семь загибов на версту.
```

Если русские дороги плохие, то, возможно, они находятся у чёрта на каком-то особом счету. Но тогда как они могут находиться у бога на том же самом месте?

Answer (score 1):

Плохие дороги могут приводить к большой смертности, а количество праведников, идущих в результате гибели в рай, к Богу, или грешников, идущих в ад, к чёрту, можно считать сопоставимым, т.к. личные качества никак не влияют на выживаемость на дороге. То есть Российская дорога — беспристрастный убийца, а потому и Бог с чёртом к ней относятся нейтрально, имеют на одном счету.

Comment: А по какой причине может быть большая смертность? Лошадей на изгибах заносит?

Comment: В песне приведена одна из причин смертности: можно околеть в долгом пути. Путнику там туго, ясно, что колдобины тяжело преодолевать. Собственно, сам текст и говорит о смертности: "Ох, дорога, ты скажи нам прямо, По тебе ли ездят на тот свет?". Что до остальных причин, то разбираться надо с автором. Я от песни не в восторге, сам с её идеей поспорил бы, но это не мешает догадываться, что подразумевал человек, который её сочинил.

Comment: Кстати, хотя лошадь не заносит, с телегой, которую она тянет, это вполне может произойти.

Comment: Спасибо, стало понятнее. А то я подумал, вдруг Вы про автомобильную дорогу пишете :)

Comment: Я нет, а за автора песни не ручаюсь)

Answer (score 1):

**Как Бог и Черт заботились о российской дороге**

У Черта было бездорожье,  а Бог создал дорогу.  Хорошо стало путнику.

Тогда Черт наделал на ней ям,  но Бог  их убрал, а пока убирал,  Черт создал  ухабы.

Если надо убежать,  то по дороге убежишь быстрее (это хорошо),  но зато и догонят вас также быстро (а это плохо).

"Да, плоха дорога, на тот свет на ней только ездить!" — ругает дорогу путник, и Черт с ним, разумеется,  согласен.  "Даже ругать плохую дорогу удобнее, когда идешь по дороге", — отвечает ему Бог.

**А теперь реальный рассказ про плохие дороги**

Да, дороги у нас извилистые, но ведь местность такая: то овраг, то лес, то болото. Как строить, обходить приходится. Вот и получается семь загибов на версту. А прямые-то, они в копеечку станут.

И расстояния не близкие, длина-то у дорог не малая! Пока в одном месте чинят, в другом уже ломается, а денег где на всё взять!

Вот и плохи дороги, да только хорошо, что бог хотя бы такие дал.

А придет время, другие построим, прямые да ровные. Должно такое время прийти.

Текст песни http://songspro.ru/9/I-u-cherta-i-u-boga-na-odnom-vidat-schetu/tekst-pesni-Dorogi-